# Why we need wait_for_sequence_state task?

Tags: uvm

As I know, the start method is blocking method, it will block the code execution until the sequence is done.
Can someone explain why we need wait_for_sequence_state task?

This is my code snipped:

```
  virtual task main_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    phase.raise_objection(this,"Test Main Objection");
    virt_seq1 = wb_conmax_virtual_sequence::type_id::create("wb_conmax_virtual_sequence",this);
    virt_seq1.start(env.wb_conmax_virt_seqr,null);
    virt_seq1.wait_for_sequence_state(UVM_FINISHED);
    phase.drop_objection(this,"Dropping Test Main Objection");
   endtask
```

Answer (score 0):

the call to the wait_for_sequence_state is obsolete here. It will return immediately.